# Eclipse/ intelliJ import custom resources (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, import

I want to import a Tools.zip resource into eclipse or intelliJ, but it just won't work. I have set the classpath to `C:\Program Files\Java\Tools.zip` and in the program I wrote "import Tools.IO.IOTools, which are the subfolders in the tools archive.

But in both eclipse and intelliJ "Tools" is red and I can't use any of the files in the archive. I also tried to unpack it but it was in vain. I am certain, that it should work because other students have it imported in the exact same way. Do you know, what I'm doing wrong? Is it maybe something related to administrator rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the archive contains java source files, unzipping them into your main source folder should work.